# ListView doesn't seem to be working

Tags: android, string, android-listview

I'm trying to create a `ListView` where you click on a row and it takes you to a page with the name and other details. I've spent many days trying to make it work, but at the moment all I have is that clicking the row takes you to a blank page. I've searched many questions but none of them add a title to the new page! Here's my listview activity:

```
package com.example.cookbook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;

public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity
{

    ArrayList<String> RecipeList;
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

           // Get the reference of ListViewRecipes
            ListView RecipeListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainListView);


             RecipeList = new ArrayList<String>();
             getRecipeNames();
             // Create The Adapter with passing ArrayList as 3rd parameter
             ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
             new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RecipeList);
             // Set The Adapter
             RecipeListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

             // register onClickListener to handle click events on each item
             RecipeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
                         // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
                        {
                            Intent i=new Intent(SecondScreenActivity.this, ThirdScreenActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("position", position);
                            startActivity(i);

                             }
                });
    }

    void getRecipeNames()
    {
        RecipeList.add("Recipe1");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe2");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe3");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe4");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe5");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe6");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe7");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe8");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe9");
        RecipeList.add("Recipe10");



    }
}
```

Here's my new page activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ThirdScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    TextView t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewPosition));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String position = intent.getStringExtra("position");

    t.setText(position);        
}   

}
```

and screen2 is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textviewPosition"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not getting any error messages in eclipse or logcat, it's just showing a blank page when I click!
Thanks for the help

edit: tried (String.valueOf(position)) instead of (position) and it now says null for every row. eg. on ThirdScreenActivity:

```
TextView t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewPosition));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String position = intent.getStringExtra("position");

    t.setText(String.valueOf(position));
```

Comment: Yes Oleksiy is right, Just call Intent i = new Intent(SecondScreenActivity.this, ThirdScreenActivity.class);
i.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(i); once. and also see the your screen2.xml is not a blank, or is this xml fil you want to load

Comment: What colour blank page?

Comment: white (which I'm pretty sure is what I set screen2 background to be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason you are not getting anything is because you are passing an int. position is an int not a string extra so the getStringExtra wont work because the extra is an int.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked,
                int position, long id) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) itemClicked;
    String strText = textView.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(SecondScreenActivity.this, ThirdScreenActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("position", strText);
    startActivity(i);
}
});
```

Comment: I had wondered about the int/string thing but I wasn't sure what to do, how should I fix it? I tried getIntExtra but that just gave errors.

Comment: do you want the position of the item in the list to be displayed (i.e. recipe4 will be 4) or do you want the text "recipe4"?

Comment: Ideally it'd be "recipe4" but just "4" would be a good start, although I guess one would use string and one would use int so it would require completely different coding. so if you have an answer, "recipe 4" would be really helpful thanks

Comment: Thanks very much james, that looks like it should work. One final thing though, "TextView" (the blue ones in your code) are coming up as errors saying they cannot be resolved, what should they be resolving to?

Comment: also make sure you have the following import: import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: ah, the quick fix option to import wasn't there before so I assumed it was something else but I've imported them now, it's working perfectly now! Thanks so much, I've literally spent a whole week trying to do that!

Comment: if you wanna pass the position as a string you should just use String.valueOf(position) as I wrote in my answer... do not create a string and do not cast the row clicked to a TextView. If you wanna get the textView, you should use findViewByID to make sure that you are getting the actual textview in to the row clicked, then you wont have problems in case you have more element inside the row later on

Comment: thats assuming he has created an id for each text view. if the list needs to change then he wont do this and casting will be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you creating the same intent and starting it twice?
You just need this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SecondScreenActivity.this, ThirdScreenActivity.class);
i.putExtra("position", position);
startActivity(i);
```

Edit:

Secondly, are you sure your screen2 contains visible elements? You should post your XML

Comment: I'd assumed one intent was to change activity and one was to send the extras, thanks for letting me know! and thanks for the quick reply as well, I'll just see if it works then post screen2 if not

Comment: It hasn't changed anything, still a blank white page

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you were passing an int as a extra:

```
i.putExtra("position", position);
```

and receiving a string:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String position = intent.getStringExtra("position");
t.setText(position);
```

...So you have to change this two lines for the following lines...

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");
t.setText(String.valueOf(position));
```

EDIT: If you wanna pass a string then do this...

```
i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
```

...So you have to receive the string on the other activity...

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String position = intent.getExtras().getString("position");
t.setText(position);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's solving my problem. I would mark it as the correct answer but james is currently changing it to strings, which is what I'd actually intended, we'll see how that goes!

Comment: @user2503325 .... Thanks very much, that's solving my problem. I would mark it as the correct answer.....¡¿

Comment: i'm sorry but james got there first :/